# tan(deg2rad()) returns odd values for degrees between 180 to 360

Tags: php, geometry

```
$degree = 179;
$aX = $valueB + ($valueA - $aY)/tan(deg2rad($degree));
```

returns 742.710038369 as $aX

but when $degree is 180;

```
$degree = 180;
$aX = $valueB + ($valueA - $aY)/tan(deg2rad($degree));
```

returns -8.1656196766E+15 as $aX

and similar values all the way to 361 when it completes a full turn and returns 857.289961631 as $aX again.

How do I fix this, do I need to convert the different value or change something else?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

EDIT;

```
$degree = 180;
$valueA = 800;
$valueB = 800;

$aY = ($valueB/64) * (64) -1;
$aX = $valueB + ($valueA - $aY)/tan(deg2rad($degree));

$aY = round($aY/64,0);
$aX = round($aX/64,0);
```

Comment: `tan(M_PI)` should be 0, but it's actually -1.2246063538224E-16 thanks to rounding.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/   it should indeed throw an exception or something...

Comment: i would say you are getting `PHP` version of plus and less infinite..

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't see where I've divided by 0? The problem is that I don't understand the return value.

Comment: You might want to explain what you are trying to accomplish, e.g. what are `$aX`, `$aY`, `$valueA` and `$valueB`. But other than that, if you want to understand what your function looks like for different values of `$aY` and `deg2rad($degree)`, see https://www.google.nl/search?q=10+%2B+(6+-+y)%2Ftan(x) (you may need to copy the whole link; I've used some arbitrary values for `$valueA` and `$valueB`, and used `x` for `deg2rad($degree)`)

Comment: @Bart here's the whole code;
$degree = 180;
$valueA = 800;
$valueB = 800;

$aY = ($valueB/64) * (64) -1;
$aX = $valueB + ($valueA - $aY)/tan(deg2rad($degree));

$aY = round($aY/64,0);
$aX = round($aX/64,0);

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant great article. It's nice/chilling to see all of these design flaws in one place. You can kind of cope when you only stumble on them one by one every 5 minutes or so :-)

Comment: @Bart added to OP for readability too.

Comment: Since PHP does no automatic rounding if you divide by an integer, you should use something like `$aY = intval($valueB/64) * (64) -1;`. At least that's what you seem to want (or your code just contains nonsense operations in that line)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark So I should store the tan in a separate value like $tan = tan(deg2rad($degree)), check if it's '0' and if it's not, it's safe to do ($valueA - $aY)/$tan?

Answer (score 0):

As other comments have pointed out, dividing by 0 either does give or should give an error when the result should be an ordinary number. The present code snippet, if indeed there's a possible motivation for it, looks like an application for [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), which represent directions in projective geometry. Representing a direction as the slope of a line with a linear expression only works when the slope is not vertical. In homogeneous coordinates, you can represent such directions easily, and you get numerical stability near such directions to boot.

That said, I cannot puzzle out what application the present code snippet might be part of, and thus whether this answer is relevant.